# Trying to get selinux to allow apache to run an executable that uses a port

Tags: apache, selinux

I am trying to get apache to run a bash script which uses ffmpeg to take snapshots from a mp4 stream. I get an "Input/Output" error where ffmpeg is blocked from accessing port 80.

I've gotten apache to run ffmpeg, it just seems to get blocked on port access.

I assume its an selinux permission problem where ffmpeg needs special permissions to be able to access port 80 (or whatever port it is) when run by apache.

The script runs fine from command line, its just launching it remotely that dies.

Thanks for your help!

> sudo semanage port -l | grep http_port
>   http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
>   pegasus_http_port_t            tcp      5988
>
> ls -Z /usr/bin/ffmpeg 
>   -rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /usr/bin/ffmpeg

From var/log/audit/audit.log:

type=AVC msg=audit(1502245154.609:23912): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=12043 comm="ffmpeg" dest=80 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:http_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket

type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1502245154.609:23912): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=3 a1=1775f00 a2=10 a3=7ffd7a6af0d0 items=0 ppid=12041 pid=12043 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="ffmpeg" exe="/usr/bin/ffmpeg" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 key=(null)

Running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01

created policy specific to access requirements - Step 7 in the documentation